# How to implement a trait for generic type?

Tags: generics, methods, rust, traits, implementation

In Rust what is the proper way of implementing traits for a generic type? I'm expecting my Vector to consist of integers or floats. Irregardless of the type I want get_magnitude() to output f64. How do I get powi() and sqrt() to work? Any workarounds? I'm stuck

```
pub struct Vector<T> {
    i: T,
    j: T,
    k: T,
}

impl<T> Vector<T> {
    fn new(i: T, j: T, k: T) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector {
            i,
            j,
            k,
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Vector<T> {
    fn get_magnitude(&self) -> f64 {
        (self.i.powi(2) + self.j.powi(2) + self.k.powi(2)).sqrt()
    }
}
```

https://www.codewars.com/kata/58ee4962dc4f81d6f400001c/rust

Comment: The only `powi` that returns `f64` in the standard library is defined on `f64`. Realistically your only choice is to abandon attempts at being generic and declare the actual type. Especially since there is no test requiring you to be generic.

Answer (score 3):

You can have `get_magnitide()` constrained to only work when `T` is applicable. And instead of constraining that `T` has a `powi()`, I'd recommend just converting them to `f64` initially and doing the math from there.

You can use the [`AsPrimitive<f64>`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/cast/trait.AsPrimitive.html#tymethod.as_) trait from the [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) crate for that:

```
use num::cast::AsPrimitive; // 0.4.0

pub struct Vector<T> {
    i: T,
    j: T,
    k: T,
}

impl<T> Vector<T> {
    fn new(i: T, j: T, k: T) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector { i, j, k }
    }
}

impl<T> Vector<T> {
    fn get_magnitude(&self) -> f64
    where
        T: AsPrimitive<f64>,
    {
        (self.i.as_().powi(2) + self.j.as_().powi(2) + self.k.as_().powi(2)).sqrt()
    }
}
```

You may also constrain the whole `Vector` struct to only work when `T` is a number via the [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.Num.html) trait:

```
use num::Num; // 0.4.0

pub struct Vector<T>
where
    T: Num
{
    i: T,
    j: T,
    k: T,
}
```

But you will still need the constraint on `get_magnitude()` since you're enforcing that it returns a `f64`.

Comment: Given this is a codewars kata, using `num` probably isn't an option.